# why is this operation equal to 1?

Tags: c, division

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
float x;
x=4/(4-1);
printf("%f\n", x);

}
```

when I try to run that on c it makes x equal to 1, i don´t understand why

Comment: `x=4/(4-1);` The right side is computed as an integer. --> `x=4./(4-1);`

Comment: Because division doesn't work as you think on integers

Comment: thx a lot, now if i want to change the 4 for a variable, for example having x=i/(i-1)?

Comment: E.g `x=(float)i/(i-1)` , `x=i/(i-1.)`

Comment: thanks, sorry i am really new at programming, why does it not work like i had typed it?

Comment: The result of an integer operation is computed as an integer rather than a floating point number. In order to compute with a floating point number, you need to mix floating point numbers or type cast (like `(float)`).

Comment: or `x = i/(i-1.0f)` or `x= 1.0f*i/(i-1)` or `x= 1.0*i/(i-1)`, or ...

Answer (score 1):

Because you are making a division between two int, so you'll obtain an int as result.

Comment: ohh so if i want to get a float as a result i have to type "(float)" and place it before the division right?

Comment: Not exactly, you need that each number is a float, for example in this way x=4.0/(4.0-1.0);